# How to I find the id of the input next to a label after mousedown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, label, mousedown

I have the following code:

```
<div class="top">
<label id="_first"><input type="checkbox" class="AA" id="first">FIRST</label>
<label id="_second"><input type="checkbox" class="BB" id="second">SECOND</label>
<label id="_first"><input type="checkbox" class="AA" id="third">THIRD</label>
</div>
```

How can I listen for a `mousedown` event when a label is clicked, then get the id of that input?

For example, If I click my pointer over the word 'THIRD', I want to set a variable to the input id = `third`. I only want to find IDs, when the input of a certain class (ie. `.BB`) is present.

I've tried something like this:

```
$('label .BB').on('mousedown', function(){
    var sel = $(this).attr('id'); // doesn't grab id of the adjacent input
});
```

Comment: and what is your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('label input.BB').click(function(e) {
  //if(e.target.type != 'checkbox' ){//check for checkbox dont fire click
  alert($(this).attr('id'))//use this context with find
  //}
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
  <label id="_first">
    <input type="checkbox" class="AA" id="first">FIRST</label>
  <label id="_second">
    <input type="checkbox" class="BB" id="second">SECOND</label>
  <label id="_first">
    <input type="checkbox" class="AA" id="third">THIRD</label>
</div>
```

Use this context with find

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work, but how do you prevent it from firing twice?

Comment: Can you use the `mousedown` selector with this?

Comment: Cool! What if I only wanted this to run on labels followed by inputs with class=`BB`? Can you modify the jquery selector to only include clicks with `label > input.BB`? Or something like that?

Comment: you could do something like the update of add condition. do you want to show only input with class BB?

Comment: Yes, I only want to listen for a click on a label with input of class `BB` and ignore label clicks that don't have this class.

Comment: @user1837608 _"Yes, I only want to listen for a click on a label with input of class BB and ignore label clicks that don't have this class."_ That is not original Question, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `for` attribute set to `id` of child `input` element for `id` at `<label>` elements. Get `.htmlFor` of `label` element at `mousedown` event.

```js
$("label").on("mousedown", function(e) {
  console.log(this.htmlFor)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
<label for="first"><input type="checkbox" class="AA" id="first">FIRST</label>
<label for="second"><input type="checkbox" class="BB" id="second">SECOND</label>
<label for="third"><input type="checkbox" class="AA" id="third">THIRD</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `for` attribute of label which will match to the `id` attribute of checkbox

HTML

```
<div class="top">
  <input type="checkbox" class="AA" id="first">
  <label for="first">First</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="BB" id="second">
  <label for="second">Second</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="AA" id="third">
  <label for="third">Third</label>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('label').on('click', function() {
  var getId = $(this).attr('for');
  console.log(getId)
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/fooys2ur/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a native javascript approach

```
var first = document.getElementById('_first');
first.setAttribute('onclick','myFunction()');

function myFunction(){
  var first = document.getElementById('_first');
  var firstID = first.getAttribute('id');
  //or
  //var firstID = first.id;
}
```